# How can I make a card widget auto re-size in flutter for flutterflow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

My name is Vigo Walker

I am making a web app, similar to ChatGPT just that with vertex AI from google and image gen with DALL-E and midjourney, I want to make the vertex AI response render as markdown for now I have this:

```
dart
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:markdown_widget/markdown_widget.dart';

class MarkDownCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MarkDownCustomWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.content,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String content;

  @override
  _MarkDownCustomWidgetState createState() => _MarkDownCustomWidgetState();
}

class _MarkDownCustomWidgetState extends State<MarkDownCustomWidget> {
  Widget buildMarkdown(BuildContext context) {
    final isDark = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
    return MarkdownWidget(
        data: widget.content, // <-- use widget.content instead of content
        config:
            isDark ? MarkdownConfig.darkConfig : MarkdownConfig.defaultConfig);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Column(
      children: [Expanded(child: buildMarkdown(context))],
    ));
  }
}
```

This code works fine, just that it is not resisable, so if the response is large, it does not make the card bigger.

I tried asking ChatGPT and he did not knew anything looked like.